# Is there a 3.3V and 12V 18650 circuit?

Tags: esp32, battery, voltage

Is there an all in one circuit which regulates charging, protects and steps up/down an 18650 battery to 12V and 3.3V at the same time, so I can power a sensor and my ESP32?

Comment: Are you asking for a ready to use module, or for a circuit, that you can build yourself?

Comment: @chrisl preferably a ready to use module

Comment: there probably is such a module ... asking where to get one is an off topic shopping question

Comment: in all ways but convenience, it would be better to use an LDO to take the battery voltage down to 3.3 and use a 12v-only controller.

Comment: @dandavis can I even use an LDO safely? Won't I need some protection against over discharge?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a 12V controller, and then adding a 3.3V switching regulator using the 12V supply. That would be 2 off-the shelf components and you're done.

Comment: You MIGHT be able to find a battery controller that has both 12V and 3.3V outputs, but if not, a 3.3V switching regulator that can convert 12V to 3.3V efficiently is **very** easy to come by.